# Springboot-KStream: Multiple StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG setup

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Could you please help me to setup multiple APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG in a springboot project, so that we can assign different NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG to each of them.

Let say, In my current topology I have 2 processors , one of them is real fast and other one is CPU intensive. Assembling them in same stream results the cpu intensive task to fall behind. If I could setup 2 separate application, then I might assign more threads to cpu intensive task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a second `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`. Spring Boot will configure one from the application properties; configure a second one with different properties. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#streams-spring).

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell